# Python, script stops at a certain line when run from CMD

Tags: python, cmd, python-idle, pyautogui

I've been writing a script that clicks my mouse every 10 seconds, and stops doing that after I click hotkey '-', and then starts again when I click the hotkey once more.
It works as described when I use python IDLE to run it, but when I run from CMD it just stops the script after the announce line : *os.system('cmd /k "msg * /v Stopped!"')*
It seems odd to me as there are more lines to execute past that..
Thank you for your help

here's the code:

```
import pyautogui, keyboard, time, os, winsound
from datetime import datetime

temp = True
work = True
while True:
    while int(datetime.now().strftime("%S")) % 10 != 0:
        temp = True
        if keyboard.is_pressed("-"):
            if work == True:
                os.system('cmd /k "msg * /v Stopped!"')
                work = False
                time.sleep(2)
                winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
            else:
                work = True
                os.system('cmd /k "msg * /v Started!"')
                time.sleep(2)
                winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
    if temp == True and work == True:
        pyautogui.click()
        temp = False
```

Comment: Try `os.system('cmd /C "msg * /v Stopped!"')` (Note `cmd /C`  instead of `cmd /k`)

Answer (score 1):

[`os.system(command)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)

> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.
> …
>  On Windows, the
> return value is that returned by the system shell after running
> `command`. The shell is given by the Windows environment variable
> `COMSPEC`: it is usually `cmd.exe`, which returns the exit status of
> the command run…

In other words, `os.system` **waits** for a return value.

On the other hand (see built-in help `cmd /?` or read [`cmd.exe` docs](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)):

> - `cmd /C string` *carries out the command specified by *string* and then terminates*
> - `cmd /K string` *carries out the command specified by *string* but **remains***

Use either

- `os.system('"msg * /v Stopped!"')`, or even
- `os.system('msg * /v Stopped!')`.

as `cmd /c` is implicit for `os.system` in Windows…